# Почему светодиоды не затухают постепенно?

Tags: c++, arduino

Хочу сделать так, чтобы после того как, светодиоды постепенно набрали максимальную мощность, также постепенно затухали, вроде код написан так как нужно, но почему то не работает так, как было задумано, светодиоды постепенно набирют максимум мощности и просто продолжают гореть.

```
int lightdiods = 0;
void setup()
{
  pinMode(6, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  
  
  if (lightdiods != 255){
     lightdiods = (lightdiods + 5);
     analogWrite(6, lightdiods);
    delay(100);}
  else if (lightdiods == 255){
    lightdiods = (lightdiods - 5);
    analogWrite(6, lightdiods);
    
    
  
  }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

Как только значение достигнет 255, оно уменьшится на 5, а на следующей итерации, которая начнется даже без задержки, значение снова увеличится на 5. Вместо этого надо было добавить переменную-инкремент и менять у нее знак при достижении крайнего положения:

```
int lightdiods{0};
int increment{5};

void loop()
{
    lightdiods += increment;
    if ((0 == lightdiods) or (255 == lightdiods))
    {
        increment *= -1;
    }
    analogWrite(6, lightdiods);
    delay(100);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но это едиснтвенное решение? Просто я новичок, для меня это сложно, но тем не менее спасибо.
Вы говорите, что "Как только значение достигнет 255, оно уменьшится на 5, а на следующей итерации, которая начнется даже без задержки, значение снова увеличится на 5", но почему тогда они постепенно набирают мощность, а не просто повышаются на 5?

Comment: @Артём *"почему тогда они постепенно набирают мощность, а не просто повышаются на 5?"* - ну дык с 0 увеличивая каждый раз по 5 значение через некоторое время достигнет 255, а потом будет болтаться между 250 и 255.